# Lua, table converted to a number?

Tags: syntax, lua, lua-table

I am simply adding numbers together but it continues to error. I used `type()` to check if `vector` is a table or not and it always said it was but it continues to say that it is a number.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and a way to fix it(the variable `vector` is a vector3 object)? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Vector3:

```
function new(x, y, z)
  return setmetatable({x = x, y = y, z = z}, meta) --{} has public variables
end
```

All of the Vector3 file here: http://pastebin.com/csBmJG36

ERROR:

> attempt to index local 'vector' (a number value)

SCRIPT:

```
function translate(object, x, y, z)
    for i, v in pairs(object) do
        if (i == "Vertices") then
            for _, q in pairs(v) do
                for l, vector in pairs(q) do
                    vector.x = vector.x + x;
                    vector.y = vector.y + y;
                    vector.z = vector.z + z;
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Where were you using `type` to check your type in that code?

Comment: Do you think you can come up with a smaller, self contained example? Links might rot in the future and 100 lines is a bit on the larger side to have a quick look . http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I guess you get the error on the first line in the innermost scope. Are you sure `object.Vertices` contains a list of lists of points, and not just a list of points? Also, that's a nice translation of the loop-switch antipattern to Lua.

Comment: Deduplicator, I am sure of it. I used `type()` in both the second and third `pairs` loop. And, `object.Vertices` contains Vector3's(table) which contain x, y, and z coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Let's refactor your code by removing the loop-switch anti-pattern:

```
function translate(object, x, y, z)
    for _, q in pairs(object.Vertices) do
        for l, vector in pairs(q) do
            -- Test the type of vector here...
            vector.x = vector.x + x;
            vector.y = vector.y + y;
            vector.z = vector.z + z;
        end
    end
end
```

So, the error occurs with an access to `object.Vertices[_][l].x`.

That would be a curious vertex-list which contains lists of vertex-lists instead.